# Refresh Datatable with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a table at which I am using jQuery Datatable. The table is being updated every 15 seconds with new data. I am using the latest version of Datatable.

How can I re-initialise the Datatable with new data without using clear method, which impacts the UI?

My Code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: /list_tasks',
    data: ajaxData,
    spinner: true,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#task_table').html(response.html)
        if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#task_table')) {
            $('#task_table').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        var dataTable=$('#task_table').DataTable({
            deferRender:true,
            destroy: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller:       true,
            scrollY:        "200px",
            bFilter:false,
            bInfo: false,
            bLengthChange:false,
             initComplete: function(settings, json) {

            },
            fnDrawCallback:function(){

            }
        });        
    }   
});
```

Comment: try this `dataTable.ajax.reload();`

Comment: Have you tried add row api of jQuery Datatable ? Ref Link : `https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel you should rely on dataTables built in [**`ajax`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) feature. If you do that, you can update the table very easy by using [**`ajax.reload()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) :

```
var dataTable =$('#task_table').DataTable( {
   ajax: {
     url: '/list_tasks',
     data: ajaxData
   },
   deferRender:true,
   scrollCollapse: true,
   scroller:       true,
   scrollY:        "200px",
   bFilter:false,
   bInfo: false,
   bLengthChange:false,
   initComplete: function(settings, json) {
   }, 
   fnDrawCallback:function(){
   }
});  

setInterval(function() {
  dataTable.ajax.reload()
}, 15000);
```

---

**Update**. You will never be able to prevent flickering or impact on the UI if you repeately inject and remove a table to the DOM, and instantiate it as a dataTable afterwards. Another approach could be to separate your table code in a different PHP script and place it inside an iframe :

```
<iframe src="table.php" id="table"></iframe>
```

Then update the iframe itself each 15 secs :

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('#table')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
}, 15000);
```

Comment: HTML table is getting build using server side templating  so cannot use datatable.ajax

Comment: @pareshm, why not take the upportunity to not create the whole table markup serverside? It will certainly run faster and give a more fluent flow, i.e not impact UI. It is quite easy.  Here is an example **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/957/**

Comment: no cannot do coz many classes and operation are done currently on that table coming from server side
completely new approach is very much time consuming
before was not using Datatable
now want to introduce

Comment: @pareshm, OK - but you will never be able to prevent flickering or impacts on the UI if repeately remove and insert a table to the DOM. The only thing I can think of is placing the table logic inside an iframe. See update.